# Copy contents of Tab Page c#

Tags: c#, tabs

I have a tab control in which one Tab page is static and other Tab pages are created dynamically through a loop . i want to copy all the data form static Tab Page . The static Tab contains one grid view.i want to copy that grid view into all dynamically created grid view but problem is that the last one contains the grid view and others are blank. Any help

```
  for (int i = 1; i <xnl.Count ; i++)
                 {
                     TabPage tb = new TabPage();

                    tb.Controls.Add(datagrid);
                   tabControl1.Controls.Add(tb);
                 }
```

Comment: Have you found an answer already?

Comment: i changed my technique now not changing tabs only reference

Answer (score 0):

i think you should Clone your grid,then add cloned instance

Answer (score 0):

A Control can only have 1 parent control, which is changed each time you add it to a new ControlCollection. You'll have to copy your gridview (including all it's properties, events and data). Perhaps a more easy way to achieve what you want is to handle the `Selected` event of the tabControl to show the grid on the currently active tab.

**Example:**

```
tabPage.Selected += (a, b) =>
                {
                    tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(grid);
                };
```

Comment: @ Corne you are saying that i will not create new controls on each tab and handle TabIndexChanged . Then how i will show selected tab 2 and contents of tab1

Comment: @abdul Sorry, you should handle the `Selected` event, not TabIndexChanged. However, from your comment, I suspect you want different content on the gridview on each tab? In that case you'll have to create a new grid on each tabpage.

Comment: ok but my grid has lot of events handled how i will manage all those events on each TAB. i want all events working on all tabs grid

Comment: The events are attached to the gridview instance, you only change the tabview on which the gridview is shown. The events will continue to work where ever it is shown. If you have to create a new gridview on each tab I advise you to create a custom gridview derived from the gridview class in which you attach your events.